# NSDateFormatter & NSString returning (null) for date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I'm am accessing a date from a JSON array, and then I want to format it to a readable date, the code is below.

```
    NSDateFormatter *expirationDateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [expirationDateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [expirationDateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"];

    NSDate *alertExpiresRealDate = [[alerts objectAtIndex:i] valueForKeyPath:@"expires"];
    NSString* alertExpiresDate = [expirationDateFormat stringFromDate:alertExpiresRealDate];
    NSLog(@"%@", alertExpiresRealDate); // 1380319200
    NSLog(@"%@", alertExpiresDate); // (null)
    NSString* alertExpires = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Expires: %@", alertExpiresDate] uppercaseString];
```

Even when I change the "setDateFormat" to be something simple like yyyy it still returns (null).

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Is `alertExpiresRealDate` an `NSDate` - doesn't look like it from your log...

Comment: What you're probably missing is that alertExpiresRealDate is probably not an NSDate.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks all. Here's what I changed it to: `NSDate *alertExpiresRealDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[[alerts objectAtIndex:i] valueForKeyPath:@"expires"] doubleValue]];`

Comment: Unfortunately, NSDateFormatter doesn't raise an exception when presented with something other than an NSDate, it just returns nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments in the question the problem was `alertExpiresRealDate` wasn't an NSDate.

Updated that line to be:

```
NSDate *alertExpiresRealDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[[alerts objectAtIndex:i] valueForKeyPath:@"expires"] doubleValue]];
```

And it works now.